# Get the quantity of sold products on a specific day, keeping all products

Tags: mysql

I'm building a database for daily sales report, for example:

*2 apples sold for 2.50 on 2021-02-12

1 apple sold for 2.00 on 2021-02-12

6 bananas sold for 3.50 on 2021-02-12

0 pears sold on 2021-02-12*

**Notice the "0 pears sold"**

I have these tables:

**Products**

| id (PK) | name | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Apple | null |
| 5 | Banana | null |
| 6 | Pear | null |

**Orders**

| id (PK) | sale_date (DATE) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-12 |
| 2 | 2021-02-12 |

**ProductOrders**
|order_id (FK)|product_id (FK)|quantity|price|
|1 | 2 (it is "Apple") | 2 | 2.50 |
|1 | 5 (it is "Banana") | 3 | 3.50 |
|2 | 2 (it is "Apple") | 1 | 2.00 |
|2 | 5 (it is "Banana") | 3 | 3.50 |

I would like to get the products sold on 2021-02-12 grouped by price, **keeping products that have not been sold** so that I can write "0", as in the example.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT
    p.id AS prod_id,
    p.name AS prod_name,
    sum(po.quantity) AS quantity_sold,
    po.price AS price
FROM products p
    JOIN ProductOrders AS po ON p.id = po.product_id
    JOIN Orders AS o ON po.order_id  = o.id
WHERE o.sale_date = THE DATE
GROUP BY p.id, po.price
ORDER BY p.name, po.price
```

With this query I get:

*2 apples sold for 2.50 on 2021-02-12

1 apple sold for 2.00 on 2021-02-12

6 bananas sold for 3.50 on 2021-02-12*

**Without the "0 pears sold"**, because the query discards the products that have not been ordered in "that date"

**How can I to edit this query to get all products, also if they has not been sold in the date?** Because I need to write 0 for the products has not been sold in "that date"

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english

## EDIT

I forgot to say that I tried to use LEFT JOIN, but the problem is that in this way, it will keep **all orders**

```
SELECT
    p.id AS prod_id,
    p.name AS prod_name,
    sum(po.quantity) AS quantity_sold,
    po.price AS price
FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN ProductOrders AS po ON p.id = po.product_id
    LEFT JOIN Orders AS o ON po.order_id  = o.id AND o.sale_date = THE DATE
GROUP BY p.id, po.price
ORDER BY p.name, po.price
```

This query will keep all "ProductOrders" so it will returns many many rows, so **I can't use this solution**

## SOLUTION

Thanks to the user nbk for this solution (I just added the WHERE clause to discard deleted products that have not orders on "THE DATE"):

```
SELECT
    p.id AS prod_id,
    p.name AS prod_name,
    p.deleted_at,
    sum(po.quantity) AS quantity_sold,
    po.price as price
FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN (ProductOrders AS po 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE sale_date = '2021-02-12') AS o ON po.order_id = o.id
    ) ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE (p.deleted_at IS NULL OR (p.deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND po.product_id IS NOT NULL))
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.deleted_at, po.price
ORDER BY p.name, po.price;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a ddl you get quicker a good result.

you have to `LEFT JOIN` the tables to get the Rows with no partners.

Also add the where clause directly to the ON Clause or else you loose the gained rows.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE products (
>   `id` INTEGER Primary Key,
>   `name` VARCHAR(6),
>   `deleted_at` VARCHAR(4)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO products
>   (`id`, `name`, `deleted_at`)
> VALUES
>   ('2', 'Apple', 'null'),
>   ('5', 'Banana', 'null'),
>   ('6', 'Pear', 'null');
>
>
>
> CREATE TABLE Orders (
>   `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
>   `sale_date` DATE
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Orders
>   (`id`, `sale_date`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2021-02-12'),
>   ('2', '2021-02-12');
>
> CREATE TABLE ProductOrders (
>   `order_id` INTEGER,
>   `product_id` VARCHAR(18),
>   `quantity` INTEGER,
>   `price` DECIMAL(10,2)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO ProductOrders
>   (`order_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, `price`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2', '2', '2.50'),
>   ('1', '5', '3', '3.50'),
>   ('2', '2', '1', '2.00'),
>   ('2', '5', '3', '3.50');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     p.id AS prod_id,
>     p.name AS prod_name,
>     sum(po.quantity) AS quantity_sold
> FROM products p
>     LEFT JOIN (ProductOrders AS po 
>     INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE sale_date = '2021-02-12') AS o ON po.order_id  = o.id)
>     ON p.id = po.product_id
> GROUP BY p.id, p.name,po.price
> ORDER BY p.name;
> ```
>
> ```
> prod_id | prod_name | quantity_sold
> ------: | :-------- | ------------:
>       2 | Apple     |             1
>       2 | Apple     |             2
>       5 | Banana    |             6
>       6 | Pear      |          null
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     p.id AS prod_id,
>     p.name AS prod_name,
>     sum(po.quantity) AS quantity_sold
> FROM products p
>     LEFT JOIN (ProductOrders AS po 
>     INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE sale_date = '2021-02-13') AS o ON po.order_id  = o.id)
>     ON p.id = po.product_id
> GROUP BY p.id, p.name,po.price
> ORDER BY p.name;
> ```
>
> ```
> prod_id | prod_name | quantity_sold
> ------: | :-------- | ------------:
>       2 | Apple     |          null
>       5 | Banana    |          null
>       6 | Pear      |          null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2ce5cf22c244790a38e7245e162dd101)*

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I edited the post, because I forgot to say that I tried the LEFT JOIN, but it would be a problem because it will return all ProductOrders (many many rows). So it is not the solution

Comment: Simpy reduce the number of joins by add also a on condition, you can only use left join to get the empty products. Please extebd your sample(my dbfiddle towith more rows that show wjat you want, as pears 0 orders was what you ask for

Comment: How can I to reduce the number of joins? The problem with the LEFT JOIN is that it returns all the orders. For example, if you try the query and you just change ```AND  o.sale_date = '2021-02-12'``` with ```AND  o.sale_date = '2021-02-13'``` It would give the same results as "2021-02-12" that is wrong

Comment: @secon25 i edited my answer, you can not reduce the joins as you need indormation from product and orders for your result, that information can only come from these tables.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working. Why did you put "p.name" in the group by? Is not p.id enough? Sorry for stupid question, as you can see I'm pretty noob, and I'm trying to undestand better the group by. One last thing, to discard old products that have been deleted (so the deleted_at column is not null) and these products have not orders in "THE DATE", should I put a condition in the WHERE clause? Because I tried to add ```WHERE p.deleted_at IS NULL```but it discards all the products that have been deleted, so if in "THE DATE" I sold a product, then it is deleted, I still have to see it

Comment: About the last question in the above comment, I think I found a way: I edited the ```WHERE p.deleted_at IS NULL``` with this ```WHERE (p.deleted_at IS NULL OR (p.deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND po.product_id IS NOT NULL))```. This should **include** the products that **have been deleted but have orders on "THE DATE"**, and it should **discard** the products that **have been deleted and don't have orders on "THE DATE"**. I hope this will not break the rest of query XD. As soon as I have time I will test this query with the real data. Thanks again!

Comment: my database has a ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY eanbled and so every column has to be in the group by or has a aggregation function. for youtrrr "üproblme" see please https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=833a2514800d13e69f4f9ea02169aad7  it is only a typo, as the column don't have actually NULL as value in my answer in the new link this is corrected

Comment: Ok, so I will add all the columns to the GROUP BY, in this way I'm sure this query will not break in future. About the deleted at, I replaced the WHERE clause with this ```WHERE (p.deleted_at IS NULL OR (p.deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND po.product_id IS NOT NULL))``` because in this way I can still see the products that have been sold also if it got deleted during the day. For example, 2021-02-12 I sold 2 pears, then "Pear" column get deleted in the same date (so deleted_at is not NULL anymore), I still want to see that "2021-02-12" I sold 2 pears

Answer (score 1):

When you don't specify the type of `JOIN` clause, by default MySQL assume you mean `INNER JOIN` which only returns records that match the predicate in your `JOIN` clause. Rather in your case you want all records from your `products` table so you should use an `OUTER JOIN`, specifically a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, to return every record from the table to the left of the `JOIN` clauses, in this case the `products` table. You can actually use the shorthand notation of `LEFT JOIN` to mean the same thing. Here's an example with your query:

```
SELECT
    p.id AS prod_id,
    p.name AS prod_name,
    sum(coalesce(po.quantity, 0)) AS quantity_sold,
    po.price AS price
FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN ProductOrders AS po ON p.id = po.product_id
    LEFT JOIN Orders AS o ON po.order_id  = o.id
WHERE o.sale_date = THE DATE 
    OR o.sale_date IS NULL
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, po.price
ORDER BY p.name, po.price
```

Notice I also added `OR o.sale_date IS NULL` to your `WHERE` clause to ensure we don't filter out the rows that don't match (i.e. the products that weren't sold on that date). When using an `OUTER JOIN`, the tables on the right side of the `JOIN` clause that don't have matching rows will have `NULL` values for their fields. We also then need to check if the `po.quantity` is `NULL` in the `SUM()` function as well so we can set it to 0 (our default value for when that `product` wasn't sold on that date).

Alternatively you can accomplish the same results with this query that leverages a `UNION ALL` with your original query in a **CTE** as well:

```
WITH CTE_ProductSales AS
(
    SELECT
        p.id AS prod_id,
        p.name AS prod_name,
        sum(po.quantity) AS quantity_sold,
        po.price AS price
    FROM products p
        JOIN ProductOrders AS po ON p.id = po.product_id
        JOIN Orders AS o ON po.order_id  = o.id
    WHERE o.sale_date = THE DATE
    GROUP BY p.id, p.name, po.price
),
CTE_ProductSales_AllProducts AS
(
    -- Products that were sold
    SELECT prod_id, prod_name, quantity_sold, price
    FROM CTE_ProductSales

    UNION ALL

    -- Products that weren't sold
    SELECT id AS prod_id, name as prod_name, 0 AS quantity_sold, 0 as price
    FROM products P
    LEFT JOIN CTE_ProductSales PS
        ON P.prod_id = PS.prod_id
    WHERE PS.prod_id IS NULL -- Products that weren't sold on the date in the CTE
)

-- Final select of products sold with products that weren't sold
SELECT prod_id, prod_name, quantity_sold, price
FROM CTE_ProductSales_AllProducts 
ORDER BY prod_name, price
```

And finally here's a 3rd way you can accomplish this if you're running a version of MySQL that doesn't have **CTEs**:

```
-- Products sold on THE DATE
SELECT
    p.id AS prod_id,
    p.name AS prod_name,
    sum(po.quantity) AS quantity_sold,
    po.price AS price
FROM products p
    JOIN ProductOrders AS po ON p.id = po.product_id
    JOIN Orders AS o ON po.order_id  = o.id
WHERE o.sale_date = THE DATE

UNION ALL

-- Products that weren't sold on THE DATE
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.id AS prod_id,
    p.name AS prod_name,
    0 AS quantity_sold,
    0 AS price
FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN ProductOrders AS po ON p.id = po.product_id
    LEFT JOIN Orders AS o ON po.order_id  = o.id
WHERE o.sale_date = THE DATE
    AND po.product_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I edited the post, because I forgot to say that I tried the LEFT JOIN, but it would be a problem because it will return all ProductOrders (many many rows). So it is not the solution

Comment: @secon25 It shouldn't return any more records than one per each `product` and it's `price` it sold for on that date, because of you're grouping, no? Also notice my query is slightly different than the one you tried with a `LEFT JOIN` (and the other answers).

Comment: @secon25 Also if the first answer I provided still isn't sufficient, please see the alternative second answer I added which theoretically should be more efficient of a query (although more verbose).

Comment: I tried the first query, if in the where clause I put a date where nothing was sold, it returns only "0 Pears", discarding "Apple" and "Banana" because the where clause says: ```WHERE o.sale_date = '2021-02-14' OR o.sale_date IS NULL```, the apples and the bananas have "sale_date" that for example is  '2021-02-12', so the condition is false for them. So I tried to remove the WHERE clause and I put the condition in the JOIN: ```LEFT JOIN Orders AS o ON po.order_id  = o.id AND o.sale_date = '2021-02-14'``` but this returns all the orders summed...

Comment: for example if I insert orders only in date "2021-02-12" the join for 2021-02-14 includes the orders on "2021-02-12".
About the second query, I can't use the WITH clause because unfortunately I'm running MySQL 5.6

Comment: @second Sorry haven't been able to test with the actual data, but I think that makes sense. Unfortunate you can't use **CTEs**, they're pretty helpful. But I added a 3rd way to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the 3rd query but It sums all the "quantity_sold" (https://imgur.com/a/WDRA1vU). So I added the GROUP BY but it is not returning "0 Pears"(https://imgur.com/a/SYNcy6Q). Am I doing something wrong?

Sorry, can I ask a noob question that has nothing to do with my problem? In the first query you put in the GROUP BY "p.name", Is not "p.id" enough? Sorry as you can see I'm pretty noob and sometimes GROUP BY is difficult to me

Comment: @secon25 Sorry I forgot to add the `DISTINCT` keyword to my 3rd query. It should now produce the results you're looking for. Please try it again and let me know. Regarding your question on `GROUP BY`, when you use that clause you can only reference fields in your `SELECT` list that are listed in the `GROUP BY` unless you put them in an **aggregate function** (like `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `COUNT()`, etc). I believe some versions of MySQL actually let you directly reference a column not in the `GROUP BY` clause anyway, not sure why, but I think it returns randomish results. I meant to mention earlier.

Comment: I tried with the ```DISTINCT``` but it returns same result https://imgur.com/a/gsOGrJS  (with GROUP BY it returns https://imgur.com/a/odHgUnN). About the ```GROUP BY``` I understand, I should put all the fields that are in ```SELECT``` to avoid that in future it will breaks. Thank you!